# Foreign Key int Array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist, database-migration

I have related table. How can I keep the relationship in this table as an array?

```
        public int TreatmentId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("TreatmentId")]
        public virtual Treatment Treatment { get; set; }
```

I want to be able to give the TreatmentId here like this;
[image]

When I make an array and try to migrate, I get the following error;

The property 'ContactPage.TreatmentId' is of type 'int[]' which is not supported by the current database provider. Either change the property CLR type, or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

```
   public int[] TreatmentId { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("TreatmentId")]
   public virtual Treatment Treatment { get; set; }
```

Comment: You can't. That's not how relational databases work. Every time you have `n-many` something you will _need_ a new table.

Comment: The following may be useful: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/database-design-basics-eb2159cf-1e30-401a-8084-bd4f9c9ca1f5 and https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/database-normalization-in-sql-with-examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot save an integer array as FK, however I have seen people adding comma separated values as string, but this design is a very bad practice and will cause you many problems.

You need to have a third Table (one of your tables is Treatments, assuming the other one is Patients), like `PatientsTreatments`:

```
public class PatientsTreatments
{
    public int PatientId { get; set;}
    public int TreatmentId { get; set;}
}
```

and then you need to add a new record for each treatment.